# Why crystal report picture object show url pictures only by lowercase "http" not by uppercase "HTTP"

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I insert a picture object in crystal report to show a picture from internet. In the [picture] tab of [Format Editor] window , I type a URL in Graphic (X+2) button.
Such as 
But it doesn't work!
I have to change the letters "HTTP" to "http", then it works.
Does anyone know why or what is the reason ? 
Thanks ~

Comment: may be because it is case sensitive

Comment: In my experience, when I type HTTP://www.google.com in my browser. My browse still bring me to Google page. In the network world , the URL and e-mail address should not case-sensitive.

Comment: thats correct. Technically it shouldnt be.. but considering it works after you have changed it to caps that implies it is.